# Adding jQuery doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, magento-1, jquery, cdn

To add the jquery, plus my own file (`main.js`), I pasted this piece of code in my `local.xml`:

```
    <block type="core/text" name="google.cdn.jquery">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script>window.jQuery||document.write('<script src="/path/to/your/jquery.js">\x3c/script>');</script><script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>]]></text>
        </action>
    </block>

    <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_js</type>
        <name>js/main.js</name>
    </action>
```

Seems alright, but when I use this function in my `main.js` file, it doesn't do anything. Not even a console error:

```
$j('.block-title').click(function(){
    alert();
});
```

I know this will probably be marked as a duplicate, but all the answers I've found don't seem to work. I have tried changing the classname, but that also did not work.

UPDATE

So I found out jQuery does work, with this:

```
var $j=jQuery.noConflict();
```

But there is still a problem.

```
$j(document).click();
```

Works fine, but when I call a class, like this:

```
 $j('.footer').click()
```

It does nothing. I checked the classname alot, and even changed a few times to test. Didn't work. Is it possible, that jQuery 1.10.2 uses another form of calling classes?

LAST UPDATE:

Seems I had forgotten to place the .click function within the $j(document).ready() function... stupid me

Comment: What happens if you use `$` instead of `$j` ? Or directly `jQuery` ?

Comment: The answer I got this from specifically said I should use $j, because of the noConflict() that was added. Using $ results in errors in the console, saying that the .click function has a property of null

Comment: Using jQuery gives the exact same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned that you should use `$j` because of the `noConflict()` I'm pretty you can fix your issue by replacing:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

With:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Edit: the problem was that the OP forgot to use `$j(document).ready` in its main js code.

Comment: It didn't do alot, except for giving a console error stating: $j(...).cycle is not a function. This error came from slideshow.js, one of the standard js files that are in the sample data

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen interesting I'm not too sure what's going on here. could you check your source code and ensure you don't have another jQuery library file loaded from somewhere else ?

Comment: I do have another jquery library file loaded, by magento itself. It's loaded by RWD default: /skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen that's probably what the issue is. Having the original magento jQuery library loaded + the one you're adding is causing issues

Comment: The weird thing is, using the original magento jQuery library, it is still nog doing anything. Even while adding the $j = jQuery.noConflict(); method.

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused. $j(document).ready does work... Is it possible, that jQuery 1.10.2 doesn't contain the .click() function yet?

Comment: $j(document).click() seems to work too, the problem lies somewhere else I guess...

Comment: try to add `$j(document).ready(function(){` before the code in your main.js and `});` after it

Comment: Oh my god, I am using jQuery for probably 3 year now... Still these stupid mistakes. Thanks alot

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen lol you're welcome